# I am getting an error "createSpyObj requires a non-empty array" with running unit tests, which were executed perfectly before

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am working on an Angular frontend unit test for updating the Sonar report,

```
Chrome Headless 93.0.4577.63 (Windows 10) ERROR
  An error was thrown in afterAll
  createSpyObj requires a non-empty array or object of method names to create spies for thrown
Chrome Headless 93.0.4577.63 (Windows 10): Executed 994 of 1041 (skipped 20) ERROR (0 secs / 11.047 secs)
Chrome Headless 93.0.4577.63 (Windows 10) ERROR
  An error was thrown in afterAll
Chrome Headless 93.0.4577.63 (Windows 10): Executed 994 of 1041 (skipped 20) ERROR (16.566 secs / 11.047 secs)
```

This is the error log I am getting. Previously all the tests ran without any problem. After a few new tests were added in a different component suddenly this error popped up. Then I removed the new tests and the new component also. But I am still getting this error. But the tests are executing without any error on the Chrome headless browser that automatically opens. Why am I getting this **ERROR**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look through the code base for `jasmine.createSpyObj` and ensure that the array is not empty.

```
// Make sure you don't see empty arrays like so when using jasmine.createSpyObj
// The array is supposed to be an array of strings of public methods
// you want to mock.

jasmine.createSpyObj([]);
jasmine.createSpyObj('SomeName', []);
```